# Grammar : So much...as..?

Tags: grammar

Could you explain to me what this sentence actually means?

''I don't know if the ticket was so much for the launch as for telling the policewoman:"(from big bang theory)

I don't quite understand this because of the use of as. Does as for in this sentence mean with regard to? or different meaning with so much?

Comment: There is something missing from the quote. It can't stand unless it includes whatever it was that the policewoman was told. What follows this quote? In its present form it is not a complete sentence.

Comment: I don't understand it either, because you haven't explained the context. Presumably it means _ticket_ in the sense 'official notification of an offence' rather than 'permit to travel or enter somewhere'? Anyway, the sense is [this one](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-so-much-as).

Comment: 'I don't know if the ticket was so much for the launch as for telling the policewoman:[something]. [arrest someone else] for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [full context](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1127386/characters/nm0374865) is...

> *I don't know if the ticket was so much for the launch as it was for you telling the policewoman "You have to frisk me. I have another rocket in my pants."*

...but for simplicity, let's pretend it was...

> *I don't know if the ticket was so much for the launch as for you being rude*

(I also deleted ***it was***, that unnecessarily refers back to ***the ticket was***.)

What the speaker *means*<sup>1</sup> could also be expressed the other way around...

> *[For all I know...]*
> *the ticket was **as much for** you being rude, **as for***
> *[...launching a model rocket in the park.]*

---

The basic comparison here is the same as...

> *A unisex toilet is **as much for** women **as** [it is for] men*

...where ***it is*** or ***it is for*** are "predictably repeated" elements that are often "deleted" (because they're obvious, even if not explicitly included).

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, that's what the *words* mean (interpreted literally). But there's little doubt that what *Leonard* (the speaker) really intends to convey is ***I'm quite sure** it was because you were so rude!*

Comment: Thank you very much for your brilliant answer. I didn't know that ''so much as'' means ''as much as'' and also ''it(ticket) was'' can be deleted in the sentence. It'd been easier for me to understand comparisons If ''it was'' had remained however I'll try to get used to the deletion of predictably repeated elements.